# When will Fragmentation appear such that a Fragment is at an lower address as the Basefragment?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, defragment

By Basefragment I mean the first fragment of a file -- containing the header etc.

Lets say I have a file which is fragmented into 3 fragments (1, 2, 3). 
1 has the lowest address. I think most file systems will order the fragments such that the first fragment (1) comes first, then 2, then 3 - if fragmentation occures. But I have read that it also may happen that for example 2 has a lower relativ address and would appear as : 2, 1, 3.

Which allocation algorithm would cause something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a file, most filesystems will store it in the first extent that is big enough to hold it.  If the file grows beyond that extent however, the file will become fragmented.  The fragment will again take the first extent big enough to hold the additional blocks, which may be an address that is lower than the original.

Different filesystems behave in different ways.  Linux filesystems prefer to allocate blocks closest to the parent directory's inode whereas NTFS prefers lower-address first and prefers unallocated blocks over previously deallocated ones.  Each system has its own merits.

Comment: Is this the only situation where this can happen that you know of?

Comment: I couldn't say. Out-of-order allocation is a modern optimization technique, so it's hard to know exactly how the filesystem driver makes those decisions without reading the code (which is monstrously complicated at this point and not possible for NTFS).